# User reputation is expanded in revision history page

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, revision-history

Why is the editor/author's reputation in ["expanded form"](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66213380/2)? Why doesn't it just say '1.1m'?

[image]

Comment: MSE dupe: [Make display of reputation in revisions list consistent with the rest of the flairs again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361478/294055)

Comment: it's not the reputation, it's the phone number ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried and he did not pick up.

Comment: @Ollie too bad, maybe because it's changing all the time ;)

Comment: @Ollie They only pick up when Jon Skeet calls ;)